# Hashtag client side implementation using jquery & javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, hashtag

```css
#input {
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="input" placeholder="testing" contenteditable>listening music #music</div>
```

I'm implementing hashtag feature (ex:- #music, #dance).

if user enter '#' character I want to hit search Api.

for Example:
 user updating status "listening music #music #dance let's rock"

here  "listening music, let's rock" is normal text and "#music", "#dance" are hashtag.

whenever user enters "#m" after "listening music", i need to hit api like "/search?q=m"

var searchData = ["music", "mango", "marks", "moon"]

user able to select one of the suggestion and space will come after hashtag automatically.

whenever user enters "#d" after "#music ", i need to hit api like "/search?q=d"

var searchData = ["dance", "danger", "dad"]

user able to select one of the suggestion and space will come after hashtag automatically.

"let's rock" is normal text.

**differentiating color of  "hashtag" and search only when user enters "#"**

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: if you see, i searched for '#m', if I selected  "music", in text box value is coming like  "#mmusic" ("#m"+"music") and i want to highlight the hashtag word.

Comment: if you see twitter, i need the same functionality like "Tweet box"

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you

```
var inputData = "listening music #music #dance let's rock";
var arrayData = inputData.split(" ");

arrayData.forEach(function(entry) {
     if(entry.startsWith(("#music") || ("#etc"))){
     // hit your api
     }
});
```

Comment: user entered "listening music " and user entered "#m", "#mu" or etc, once user selected any of the suggestion i want  "#m" or "#mu" or etc become "#selectedItem", for me it's coming like "#mselectedItem" or "#muselectedItem"
and that tag should be in different color or any other (css).

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `keyup` event to your input to check for hashtag starting words. When a match is found, you call your AJAX. Like so:

```
var ajax;

$('#input').keyup(function() {

    var tags = $(this).val().split(' ');
    var lastTag = tags.pop();

    if (/#\S+\b/.test(lastTag)) {
        // abort previous ajax if still running
        if (ajax && ajax.abort && ajax.readyState !== 4)
            ajax.abort();

        // hit your search api
        ajax = $.getJson('/search', { q: lastTag })
               .done(function (data) {
                   // manage your response data here
                   // show suggestions and handle picking one
               });
    }
});
```

EDIT: Completely redone logic, much simpler and more compact

Comment: Hi rabelloo,

Thanks for your reply, I have tried your code but always "ajax" is coming undefined and first-time value of "currentHashtagIndex" is always coming "-1". Can you recheck your script and update it.

Comment: Yea, my mistake, refactored the code while writing and left the variables inside the `keypress` event scope. The ajax is always undefined because the code never managed to get to $.getJson thanks to the previous error. Please try the updated code

Comment: I also just realized you do not need a `searching` variable, you can use `currentHashtagIndex`. Updated code to reflect that

Comment: Hi Rabelloo,

Thank you, I have checked the updated code as well, the 'index' and 'query parameter' values are not correct. you can check this link [https://jsfiddle.net/5a9c4f87/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/5a9c4f87/2/).

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/5a9c4f87/5/](https://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/5a9c4f87/5/)
I updated the code here, Ignore the previous comment link.
the 'index' and 'query parameter' values are not correct.

Comment: Thanks, @rabello.
 I'm implementing the feature same like "twitter box".
here is the sample code, but still I'm facing few issues, you can check here.
[http://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/4xyo4zfa/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/DevendraTata/4xyo4zfa/2/)

Comment: What are the issues you're facing? Couldn't find one with the jsfiddle.

Comment: In that above mentioned link, i'm using content editable div element, cursor is jumping one position to other position. if i delete all the text inside the element, the div content editable stops working. 
issue 1:(div content editable stops working)
steps1: type somingthing inside element.
stept2: delete all the text you entered then you will find the issue.
issue 2: (cursor jumping one position to other position)
step1: type any link www.example.com, you will face this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately those issues have nothing to do with the original question. Please open another question for them